# How to fix this Text.get()?

Tags: python, tkinter

Since I implemented `get("1.0", END)` my app won't even start up anymore.
Anything I can do to fix this issue? I have tried everything..

Tried several different indexes, but as I want the full text string from that Textfield a different index is not an option.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import ttk
import datetime
import csv

window = Tk()
window.resizable(0, 0)
mainframe = Frame(window)
mainframe.grid()
mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)
mainframe.rowconfigure(4, weight = 1)

# Button functions
def save_csv():
    # variables
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    name = name_textfield.get()
    company = company_textfield.get()
    phone = phone_textfield.get()
    mail = mail_textfield.get()
    reason = reason_textfield.get("1.0", END)

    with open("Data.csv", "a") as d:
        w = csv.writer(d, dialect ="excel-tab")
        w.writerow([now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"), name, company, phone, mail, reason])
    d.close()

# Name
name_label = Label(mainframe, text = "Naam:")
name_label.grid(row = 0)
name_textfield = Entry(mainframe)
name_textfield.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

# Company
company_label = Label(mainframe, text = "Bedrijf:")
company_label.grid(row = 1)
company_textfield = Entry(mainframe)
company_textfield.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

# Phone number
phone_label = Label(mainframe, text ="Telefoon:")
phone_label.grid(row = 2)
phone_textfield = Entry(mainframe)
phone_textfield.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

# Mail Address
mail_label = Label(mainframe, text ="Mail:")
mail_label.grid(row = 3)
mail_textfield = Entry(mainframe)
mail_textfield.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

# Reason
reason_label = Label(mainframe, text ="Reden:")
reason_label.grid(row = 4)
reason_textfield = Text(mainframe, height = 10, width = 23, wrap = WORD, font = ("Arial", 13), highlightcolor = "#87b2e8", highlightbackground = "Grey", highlightthickness = 1)
reason_textfield.grid(row = 4, column = 1)

# Button
export = ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Save", command = save_csv())
export.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
export.pack()

mainframe.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I try to run your script I get a `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by grid` from the line `export.pack()` — so that's the problem (you can't mix geometry managers in the same frame).

Comment: So I have to seperate every Textfield in a different frame? Or can I only seperate that pasrticular textfield in a seperate frame?

Comment: No, just use `export.grid(...)` to avoid mixing `pack()` and `grid()` calls.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Got a new problem now though, it seems that no value is stored in those variables or it cannot export them to the .csv.. Got some more puzzling to do.

Comment: When you're setting your `ttk.Button`'s `command` keyword-parameter, don't invoke the function like you're doing. Do this: `..., command = save_csv)`

Comment: Aah, yes that worked! Thank you very much mate! Really appriciate the help!